# Get rid of row in result of Google Spreadsheets query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I use the following formula in my Google Spreadsheet:

```
QUERY(Inkomster!A2:G;"SELECT SUM(C) WHERE G="&B3&" AND F='"&A3&"'")
```

This returns the following (On two different rows that is)

```
H1=sum
H2=3720
```

I don't want the result of the query to return two rows, I'm not interested in the first row. Just the second one. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Your line of code is impossible to interpret without know what cells `B3` and `A3` are.

Comment: Can you give me some feedback on the answer I gave you? Did it work?

Comment: Sorry about that. I tried it know and it did indeed work. However i'd already solved it using query without Sum, and then encapsulate the query method with sum().

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following formula for that:

```
INDEX(QUERY(Inkomster!A2:G;"SELECT SUM(C) WHERE G="&B3&" AND F='"&A3&"'"),2,0)
```

The `2` references the row number and the `0 or 1` references the column number

Comment: Thanks for this.  This really needs be in the documentation for the QUERY function: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the original poster was just looking to get rid of the "sum" header. The easiest way to do this is:

```
=QUERY(Inkomster!A2:G;"SELECT SUM(C) WHERE G="&B3&" AND F='"&A3&"' label SUM(C)''")
```