# Can you do a UNION SELECT in a Google Sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-arrays

I've got a Google Sheet linked to a form which collects replies from three different people on the same subject using the same form and editing three times.  This creates a sheet which contains three columns stating where the three people are located.

I need to produce a view/query that takes those three columns and puts them 'underneath' each other, and not next to each other.  In a database I would have done something like the query below, I've called my 'sheet' tblMain, and stated the relevant four columns (I also need the subject ID).

tblMain:

```
ID        RALocation        RBLocation        RCLocation
```

Query:

```
Select ID, RALocation as Location, 'RA' as Role from tblMain
Union
Select ID, RBLocation as Location, 'RB' as Role from tblMain
Union
Select ID, RCLocation as Location, 'RC' as Role from tblMain
```

Does anyone know if there is a way of doing this in Google Sheets? I don't mind building more than one sheet and then combining them at the end, but I'm a bit stuck at how to do this.

Comment: Are the number of rows fixed or it will be change over time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I offer two versions, depending on whether blank cells should be kept. The basic idea is the same:

1. Pick a character that is not contained in your table (e.g., an exotic Unicode character  accessible via [`CHAR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094120?hl=en)).
2. Use it in the [`JOIN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094077?hl=en) command for each of three columns.
3. Concatenate the results, adding the character in between.
4. [`SPLIT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en) the concatenated string by the same character.
5. [`TRANSPOSE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en) the result.

For example:

```
=TRANSPOSE( SPLIT( JOIN(CHAR(57344),A1:A) &CHAR(57344)& JOIN(CHAR(57344),B1:B) &CHAR(57344)& JOIN(CHAR(57344),C1:C), CHAR(57344) ) )
```

where for joining/splitting, I picked the character `CHAR(57344)`, which is [designated for private use](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/e000/index.htm) and therefore should not be present in any valid input.

The above formula **removes blank entries**, because this is what `SPLIT` does. This may be convenient if your data does not have blanks: saves you the trouble of tracking where the last row of the data is. But other times, blanks should be preserved.

To preserve blanks, I follow [the answer by Jacob Jan Tuinstra](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/57710/79865) except that I used another private use Unicode instead of space (who knows, maybe you have some cells that contain just a space and you want to keep those). This involves two extra steps: after joining everything as before, I use `SUBSTITUTE` to replace `CHAR(57344)` by `CHAR(57344)&CHAR(57345)`, then split as before, and replace `CHAR(57345)` by empty string.

```
=TRANSPOSE( ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE( SPLIT( SUBSTITUTE(...joins... , CHAR(57344),CHAR(57344)&CHAR(57345)), CHAR(57344) ), CHAR(57345), "")))
```

The full result looks like this (notice that now I specify where the last row of data is):

```
=TRANSPOSE( ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE( SPLIT( SUBSTITUTE(JOIN(CHAR(57344),A1:A9) &CHAR(57344)& JOIN(CHAR(57344),B1:B9) &CHAR(57344)& JOIN(CHAR(57344),C1:C9), CHAR(57344),CHAR(57344)&CHAR(57345)), CHAR(57344) ), CHAR(57345), "" )))
```

One more caveat:  strings in Google Sheets cannot exceed 50000 characters in length. If your data is too large for string-based approach to work, use a script ([this one](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/57712/79865) is a good place to start).

Comment: That works a treat, and I can combine them to get the right result.  Only thing I'm now trying to do is to get it to respect NULL values and pull them over, it turns out that your FILTER wasn't needed, it will take them out if it finds a NULL values.  Any idea how I get it to respect the NULL?

Comment: Actually, the "other answer" is a partial answer at this time. Besides other alternatives, the relevant missing part is about how to use embedded arrays instead of the UNION-SELECT approach.

Comment: Wonderful.  I'll probably have to look at the script for when our pilot is over but for now I've got enough to go on.  People here are really helpful, thank you all!

Answer (score 8):

It is possible to make a union in Google Spreadsheet very easily nowadays with this formula:

```
={'Sheet1'!A2:A;'Sheet2'!A2:A;'Sheet3'!A2:A}
```

See more info in Google Docs Help: [Using arrays in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)

Comment: When I dropped the final row number as in this example it only returned the first set. Adding a final row number fixed this for me.

Comment: Not sure how it behaved back in 2016, but if I try this today with multiple columns (`A1:Z`) then it seems to select the first 1000 rows from sheet 1 (implicitly `A1:Z1000`?), places them in the merge sheet, then gets the first 1000 rows from sheet 2 and places them below the sheet 1 rows **without removing empty rows** (so starting at row 1001). Instead, I went with `={QUERY('Sheet1'!A1:Z,"select * where A<>''");QUERY('Sheet2'!A1:Z,"select * where A<>''")}` that checks whether the first column A is non-empty to avoid blank rows in a crude way. Either way, formatting is lost unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

## Short Answer

Google Sheets is a very powerful tool that have several alternatives to achieve a result similar to UNION-SELECT.

## Alternatives

### Embedded arrays

An alternative to use SPLIT-TRANSPOSE-JOIN-CHAR way is to use embedded arrays. One advantage of this method is that it doesn't require to construct/deconstruct strings, so the limit of the number of characters it's not relevant.

[image: Emdedded array]

#### Filtering

The above could be used in combination with [FILTER()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197?hl=en) for those cases that require filtering to have a similar behavior of UNION-SELECT. Example

```
={Filter(A1:B2, B1:B2=2);Filter(D1:E2, E1:E2=6);Filter(G1:H2, H1:H2=12)}
```

Also could be used in combination with [QUERY()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) but its results includes a headers line. To learn about how to get rid of the headers see [Get rid of row in result of Google Spreadsheets query](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/39614/get-rid-of-row-in-result-of-google-spreadsheets-query).

### How to create a column of values

Use TRANSPOSE-SPLIT-REPT to create a column of values.

```
={Transpose(Split(REPT("RA,",6),","))}
```

Also QUERY() could be used to create a column of values, but removing the headers row could make the formula more complex. Use it only if the string length limitations cause problems.

## Solution using Embedded Arrays and TRANSPOSE-SPLIT-REPT

Assume that the range tblMain is A1:D7, where A1:D1 is the table headers, and the data is in A2:D7.

```
={{"ID";A2:A7;A2:A7;A2:A7},
{"Location";B2:B7;C2:C7;D2:D7},{"Role";
Transpose(Split(REPT("RA,",6),","));
Transpose(Split(REPT("RB,",6),","));
Transpose(Split(REPT("RC,",6),","))}}
```

## References

[Appending google spreadsheet arrays - StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15985637/appending-google-spreadsheet-arrays)

Comment: You have to read more answers from me ;). I didn't find yet a official help articles about this. I know that there threads in the Google Products Forums and over the Internet, like the reference that I already included.

Comment: Thank you for this, I'm currently looking at the last solution, I think it will do very nicely for our pilot!