# Combine two charts in one and auto-update them

Tags: google-sheets

I have two tabs `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` with two columns each: `Date` and `Temperature`. I want a *single* chart of temperatures against date.

The problem is that the date columns are not necessarily identical (some dates are missing from some sheets). So, what I want to do is (full outer) join of the two tables on `Date` and then plot the two `Temperature` columns against the combined `Date` column.

The other problem is that new records are updated daily to the sheets and I want the chart to be updated automatically as it happens.

This can be relatively easily done in `R` or `Python`; however, it would be nice to do this in a more "visually interactive" environment.

Thus, my questions are: how to combine the two `Temperature` vs `Date` charts into one (taking care of the missing data) *automatically* so that no action is required when the sheets are updated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [embedded arrays](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/80394) to join the two data sets for the purpose of plotting. For example, if your data is in columns A and B of two sheets, and has a header row, the following will join and sort the two sets:

```
={Sheet1!A1:B1; sort({filter(Sheet1!A2:B, len(Sheet1!A2:A)); filter(Sheet2!A2:B, len(Sheet2!A2:A))}, 1, true)}
```

Explanation:

- `Sheet1!A1:B1` grabs the header row. The semicolon after it works as row separator in embedded arrays.
- `filter(Sheet1!A2:B, len(Sheet1!A2:A))` takes all A-B cells from Sheet1 with nonempty A entry (i.e., filters out blank rows)
- `filter(Sheet2!A2:B, len(Sheet2!A2:A))` does the same for Sheet2. Separated by ; these get stacked one over the other.
- `sort({...}, 1, true)` sorts by the first column, ascending.

---

You can also combine non-consecutive columns in this way, like E and J. The embedded array would have the structure

```
{Sheet1!E,  Sheet1!J; Sheet2!E, Sheet2!J}
```

where commas separate columns and semicolon separates rows. Specifically.

```
={filter(Sheet1!E2:E, len(Sheet1!E2:E)), filter(Sheet1!J2:J, len(Sheet1!E2:E)); filter(Sheet2!E2:E, len(Sheet2!E2:E)), filter(Sheet2!J2:J, len(Sheet2!E2:E))}
```

(and then apply `sort`, as before).

Note that both columns must be filtered by the same criterion (whatever it is) to make sure their contents align.

Comment: Does this requite that the columns are adjacent?

Comment: What if my columns are `E` and `J` instead of `A` and `B`? Thanks!

Comment: Added this to the answer.

Comment: thanks - do I need to make sure that the date columns are identical and increasing myself? I.e., what I want is `full outer join` (in the SQL sense)-is it what your code will somehow accomplish?

Comment: I left out `sort` and headers from the non-consecutive version because they are the same as before, and the formula is long enough already... You can combine based on another criteria by changing the second parameter of `filter`: e.g. filtering with `len(Sheet1!E2:E)+len(Sheet1!J2:J)` picks the rows where at least one of two columns is nonempty. If you want to do more SQL-like stuff, see [`query`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en).